# How to create a SAS macro variable name from another macro variable and a string?

Tags: macros, sas, cat

Suppose I have a dataset with variables named `var1` and `var1_test`. I am writing a macro with input `var1`. Now I am looking for a way to create `var1_test` from `var1` and the string `"_test"`. Eventually, I want to use this variable in a where condition. I tried the following:

```
%macro some_name(var =);

   %let var2 = %sysfunc(catx(&var., '_test'));

   proc sql;
    select ...
        from ...
           where &var2. = 1;
quit;

%mend;
```

Comment: Try this: `%let var2 = &var._test;`

Comment: Very simple. Thank you :-)

Comment: Are you trying to create a macro variable named `var2` or do you want the name to be `var1_test` ? Or doesn't it matter as long as it can go down into the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `cat` functions with macro variables in the macro language.  They're just open text, so just putting more text next to them automatically concatenates.

```
%let var2 = &var._test;
```

You're also using the wrong CAT function, `catx` is for putting a delimiter in the middle so the first argument is the delimiter (so it would not concatenate anything, as it only sees one thing to concatenate).  You also have quotation marks around the argument, which are not correct in `%sysfunc` - quotation marks in that context are treated as actual characters, not as string delimiters.